# Renaming a window in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm using `bind-key + ,` to rename my windows, but as soon as I type a command the name reverts back to the current working directory.

Is it possible to make the window name permanent?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The automatic rename function is turned on. Add the following to your `.tmux.conf` file (and/or run from the command line to have it take effect immediately):

```
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
```

Comment: Strange, the option is going through but this is not working for me. I both executed it from the command line, and reloaded tmux config.

Comment: I had to add this as well: `set-option -g allow-rename off`. More info [here](http://superuser.com/questions/306028/tmux-and-zsh-custom-prompt-bug-with-window-name).

Answer (score 1):

Per [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/796744/450439), I made the following change to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# NO, window name keeps changing
# set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# YES, window name sticks
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```